# Infopath 2007 and migrating datasources based on webservices

Tags: web-services, migration, infopath

I am developing Infopath forms (not web-enabled) based on webservices that I host locally on my development machine.  when the form and webservice is ready to deploy to a test/QA/Production server I have to go into the form and modify the data connections each and every time I have to point it to the relevant webservices, depending on the environment (dev/test/qa/prod).

Is there anything (scripts, programs, etc) that would be able to assist in the Infopath migration process.

I have put up with it unitl now, but as I develop more and more forms the pain is increasing.  Perhaps I just need to modify my work practice.

Has anybody else had similar issues?